# Создание pdf файла в eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, jar, export

Я могу создать жар файл который будет создавать пдф. Моя программа должна работать:

1. ввод данных в Frame1
2. нажатие на кнопку расчета Frame1
3. вывод окна Frame3 на котором видны результаты расчета (текст+картинка+кнопка печать)
4. после нажатия кнопки на Frame3 - "qwe" полжен создаваться пдф на диске Д.

Программа работает правильно в eclipsce, но при экспорте пункт с созданием пдф не работает.

```css
 import java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Component;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.FontMetrics;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.math.RoundingMode;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JComboBox;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTable;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
 import javax.swing.UIManager;
 import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
 import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

 import java.io.File; 
 import java.io.IOException;
   
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument; 
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage; 
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font;
 
 
 
 --- 
 some code
 ---
     final JFrame Frame3 = new JFrame();
     Frame3.setResizable(false);
     Frame3.setVisible(true);
     Frame3.setTitle("Расчет");
     Frame3.setBackground(new Color(224, 255, 255));
     Frame3.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(240, 250, 255));
     Frame3.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 16));
     Frame3.setSize(raz_x_f, raz_y_f);
     Frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
     Frame3.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
     Frame3.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

         RoundedButton Button_pdf = new RoundedButton("qwe");
         Button_pdf.setBackground(new Color(190, 220, 255));
         Button_pdf.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 16));
         Button_pdf.setBounds(raz_y_f-50, 20, 100, 26);
         Frame3.getContentPane().add(Button_pdf);
         Button_pdf.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
          press = press + 1;
          try {              
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
                 document.addPage(page);
                
               PDPage page0 = document.getPage(0);
               PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page0);                                        

               PDFont font = PDType0Font.load( document, new File("src/resources/FreeSans.ttf") );
               contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);
               contentStream.beginText();   
               contentStream.setFont(font, 12);

               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 800);
               contentStream.showText("1");
               contentStream.newLine(); 
               contentStream.showText("2");
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(textField_1.getText()))); 
               contentStream.newLine();
               
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-200, 00);
               contentStream.showText("3"); 
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText()))); 
               contentStream.newLine();               

               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-200, 00);
               contentStream.showText("4"); 
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText()))); 
               contentStream.newLine();               
               
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-200, 00);
               contentStream.showText("5"); 
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(String.valueOf(L_tr)); 
               contentStream.newLine();
               
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-200, 00);
               contentStream.showText("6"); 
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(comboBox_2st); 
               contentStream.newLine();
               
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-200, 00);
               contentStream.showText("7"); 
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(comboBox_3st); 
               contentStream.newLine();
               
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-200, 00);
               contentStream.showText("8"); 
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(200, 00);
               contentStream.showText(comboBox_4st); 
               contentStream.newLine();
               contentStream.newLine();
               
               contentStream.endText();

               contentStream.close();

               document.save("D:/result" + press + ".pdf");
               document.close();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame3, "pdf done");           
           } catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }
        } 
        });
```

Comment: Вы про StackTrace что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Нашел ошибку. Не находило стиль текста.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было добавить стиль текста в корень и изменить путь на : PDFont font = PDType0Font.load( document, new File("FreeSans.ttf") );